# Is there a way to have users access my Google Cloud AI Platform Notebook Instance easily?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, jupyter-lab, google-cloud-sdk, google-cloud-ai

I am new to Google Cloud AI Platform. I am running a AI Platform Notebook Instance with a service account. I have successfully added another user to my project, but it seems too involved for new users just to launch our shared notebook. I have ventured into Google SDK. If I add them to my project through my Project dashboard, is there a easy way for them to launch the notebook instance? I have not found much through documentation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @DazWilkin. I ended up sharing the GCP project with my team, and had them launch our shared notebook through the GCP dashboard. If the notebook instance is running, you are able to bookmark the link for future use. The link is unique to each user, so it is not able to be shared/sent to others that way. But, like I said as long as the notebook instance is running, you are able to launch it via a bookmarked link.